# Constant Power Loads in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, load, constant-power

Could someone help me understand what is happening in B1 when stepping between P = 2.9 W and 3.0 W?

[image: Constant Power @ 2.9 W]

[image: Constant Power @ 3.0 W]

Comment: please show the actual sim output

Comment: For P = 2.9 W:
       --- Operating Point ---

V(v_source):  75  voltage
V(v_load):  74.1137  voltage
I(B1):  0.0391291  device_current
I(R_wire):  0.0391291  device_current
I(V1):  -0.0391291  device_current

Comment: For P = 3.0 W:        --- Operating Point ---

V(v_source):  75  voltage
V(v_load):  0.626573  voltage
I(B1):  3.2836  device_current
I(R_wire):  3.2836  device_current
I(V1):  -3.2836  device_current

Comment: I meant the graphs

Comment: I switched to transient analysis and got these: https://imgur.com/a/7I8xUyV & https://imgur.com/a/A8geISy

Comment: @Aaron OP is showing the result of `.op`, the output is in the form of `.op` labels, what you see there.

Comment: @MemorX86 Just a minor note: `.op` doesn't take any arguments, so `startup` or any time range make no sense in there. It does look strange, I'm looking into it.

Comment: You are right, it does nothing (in this case), just left there from when i switch back and forth between transient and operating point analysis. I think it is just ignored by .op.

Comment: @MemorX86 You can add an `.op` label and a `.tran 1` (`startup` is not needed here). The transient analysis will ignore the `.op`, and when you need only `.op`, simply `Ctrl+RClick` on the `.tran 1` to comment it out.

Answer (score 2):

The constant power source is (still) undocumented, but you can read a bit about it [here](https://ltwiki.org/?title=Undocumented_LTspice#B-Sources) (see the **Bn P=f(...)** part):

> In order to avoid large currents at voltages near zero, the arbitrary power sink/sources foldbacks to resistive behavior when the absolute value of voltage across the device falls below a default value of 1 volt.  The foldback point may be modified by specifying a **VprXover** parameter for the device, e.g. **VprXover=50mV**.

Judging by the value of that resistor, it was deliberately chosen like that (which could have been a normal one with `22.65` as value, without the `R=`, which makes it a behavioural resistor; nothing wrong, though). Maybe it was reached through testing. At any rate, if you'll make the load `P=p VprXover=x` and use `.op` with:

```
.step param x 0.1 1 0.1
.step param p list 2.9 3
```

you'll get a plot with the variation of <some quantity> over that `x`. If you then plot the voltage across the load you'll see this:

[image: VprXover limit]

Because the default value for `VprXover` is `1`, the folding happens right around the `1 V` value. If that is what's biting your rear, simply change `VprXover` to a different value. For `P=3` use `VprXover=2`, for example, and it will work. Adjust accordingly for whatever power you need. Don't forget that it's up to the user to do this, LTspice can't read minds. No SPICE can.

Comment: This might be a good reference for beginners if they're new to constant power loads and the `vprxover` parameter:  https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-modeling-constant-power-loads.html

Comment: @SteKulov That's a good link, it certainly has better words. *blush*

Comment: Thanks for all the help, ill have to do some reading :)